# Puppet: Could not find init script for 'squid'

Tags: puppet

I'm using Puppet to install ufdbGuard which requires Squid 2.7 (which is correctly installed and working properly).

Here is the relevant class:

```
class pns_client::squid {

package { 'squid':
  ensure => present,
  before => File['/etc/squid/squid.conf'],
}


if $::ufdbguard_installed == "true" {
    $squidconf = 'puppet:///modules/pns_client/squid.conf_ufdbguard'
} else {
    $squidconf = 'puppet:///modules/pns_client/squid.conf'
}

notify{$squidconf:}

file { '/etc/squid/squid.conf':
  ensure => file,
  mode   => 644,
  source => $squidconf,
}

service { 'squid':
  ensure     => running,
  enable     => true,
  hasrestart => true,
  hasstatus  => true,
  subscribe  => File['/etc/squid/squid.conf'],
}
}
```

When running, I get this error:

```
err: /Stage[main]/Pns_client::Squid/Service[squid]: Could not evaluate: Could not find init script for 'squid'
```

This happens on all freshly-installed Debian 6 and Unbuntu 10.04/11.04 machines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your first Ubuntu server installation? If so you should know that many packages have transitioned from traditional init.d scripts to upstart. Squid would be such a package. This means there is no real `/etc/init.d/squid`. Instead this is a symlink, but you should be able to see it if you do an `ls -la /etc/init.d`. The real start script is an upstart task in `/etc/init/squid.conf`.

You need to change your manifest's `service` definition to this:

```
service { 'squid':
  ensure     => 'running',
  provider   => 'upstart',
  hasrestart => 'true',
  hasstatus  => 'true',
  subscribe  => File['/etc/squid/squid.conf'],
}
```

Note that the upstart puppet provider can not `enable` a service, so this directive should not be included.

Comment: I can't see the symlink in that directory and I get `Invalid service provider 'upstart'` from puppet. However, squid is up and running...

Comment: Upstart has been a valid Puppet provider since 2.7.0, I think. You should upgrade your Puppet setup (use apt.puppetlabs.com). The init.d symlink is just for convenience and not necessary for starting anything via upstart. It is weird though, that your system seems to be missing that symlink. It seems you somehow broke your installation.

Comment: I redid the machine from scratch and the same problem applies. Let me try to upgrade Puppet to see if it makes a difference...

Comment: Upgraded to Puppet 2.7.11 and still same result. Damn it...

Comment: Then you might have bigger problems than puppet or squid. I don't know what to tell you, I have been using upstart as a puppet service provider for months now, works fine. Did you also upgrade your puppetmaster?

Comment: Stupid me... after the puppet upgrade I forgot to add `provider   => 'upstart',`... works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Squid seems to be called `squid3` in apt-get and this error message *does* happen when the package name is wrong.

Comment: I'm using Squid 2.7.STABLE9 though.

Comment: @chris: then why don't you look in /etc/init.d and find out what the init script and thus the puppet service name is called?

Comment: I can't find anything related to squid there...

Comment: How do you stop and start squid?  And for that matter, how did you install it?

Comment: service squid start/stop. I used apt-get install squid.

Comment: Squid has transitioned from traditional init.d to upstart, so the start script is really `/etc/init/squid.conf`. You need to change your manifest's service definition. I have added an answer to explain.

Answer (score 2):

This simply means there's no `/etc/init.d/squid`, or it is not executable. Find out what the correct name is, and set either `name` or `path` to the correct value.

Comment: How can I find the correct name?

Comment: @chris `dpkg -L squid-package-name | grep /etc/init.d`.

Comment: returns nothing. As a double check, on a working machine it returns `/etc/init.d/squid`

Comment: @chris Debian 6 has two squid packages: squid and squid3. As you can see [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/squid/filelist) and [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/squid3/filelist), both contain something on `init.d`. So, if you don't have it, the package is not the official package, or has been corrupted. Do an `apt-get update`, then `purge` and `install` the package again.

Comment: Right for Debian, but still nothing in Ubuntu. I switched to upstart which solved it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, where the solution looked like this (link to bug report included):

```
  file { $upstartfile:
    ensure => present,
    source => "puppet:///elasticsearch/etc-init-elasticsearch.conf",
  }

  # for http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/14297
  file { '/etc/init.d/elasticsearch':
    ensure => link,
    target => "/lib/init/upstart-job",
  }

  service { 'elasticsearch':
    ensure        => running, 
    hasrestart    => true,
    hasstatus     => true,
    provider      => 'upstart',
    subscribe     => [ File[$upstartfile], File['/etc/init.d/elasticsearch'] ],
  }
```

I.e. a symlink in `/etc/init.d` named `elasticsearch` to `/lib/init/upstart-job`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this problem is due to the fact that Puppet do not executes the manifest sequentially. So Puppet can try to starts the Squid service before to install the Squid package and of course this causes an error.

You have then to manage the dependencies of the different tasks. Try to make this change :

```
service { 'squid':
  ensure     => running,
  enable     => true,
  hasrestart => true,
  hasstatus  => true,
  subscribe  => File['/etc/squid/squid.conf'],
  require => Package['squid'],
}
```

Good luck !

Comment: Squid is installed and already running.